# After update composer laravel giving ReflectionException error what i do?

Tags: laravel-5, composer-php

I am working on laravel project. i am new in laravel.i installed laravel with adminlte. Laravel working fine with my own created controller but when i open auth/login or logout and public/home it giving me ReflectionException error

```
ReflectionException in Container.php line 741:
Class web does not exist
in Container.php line 741
at ReflectionClass->__construct('web') in Container.php line 741
at Container->build('web', array()) in Container.php line 631
at Container->make('web', array()) in Application.php line 674
at Application->make('web') in Pipeline.php line 123
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Router.php line 710
at Router->runRouteWithinStack(object(Route), object(Request)) in Router.php line 675
at Router->dispatchToRoute(object(Request)) in Router.php line 635
at Router->dispatch(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 236
at Kernel->Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 139
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 50
at VerifyCsrfToken->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(VerifyCsrfToken), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in ShareErrorsFromSession.php line 49
at ShareErrorsFromSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(ShareErrorsFromSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in StartSession.php line 62
at StartSession->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(StartSession), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in AddQueuedCookiesToResponse.php line 37
at AddQueuedCookiesToResponse->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(AddQueuedCookiesToResponse), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in EncryptCookies.php line 59
at EncryptCookies->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(EncryptCookies), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request)) in CheckForMaintenanceMode.php line 44
at CheckForMaintenanceMode->handle(object(Request), object(Closure))
at call_user_func_array(array(object(CheckForMaintenanceMode), 'handle'), array(object(Request), object(Closure))) in Pipeline.php line 124
at Pipeline->Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}(object(Request))
at call_user_func(object(Closure), object(Request)) in Pipeline.php line 103
at Pipeline->then(object(Closure)) in Kernel.php line 122
at Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(object(Request)) in Kernel.php line 87
at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in index.php line 54
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because some controller tries to use the `web` middleware group. 
https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/middleware#middleware-groups

You can define this group in you `Http\Kernel.php` to fix the problem:

```
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],
];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Change in composer.json this:**

"acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel": "1.*"

**for this:**

"acacha/admin-lte-template-laravel": "1.0.5"

**And run:** 
composer update

**More info here:**
https://github.com/acacha/adminlte-laravel/issues/35

Comment: i was trying to run above solution but i have internet problem. i run command "composer update" due to internet problem somehow it taking so much time then close cmd and restart it and trying to run command again now it giving me error 
FatalErrorException in ProviderRepository.php line 146:
Class 'Acacha\AdminLTETemplateLaravel\app\Providers\AdminLTETemplateServiceProvider' not found
what i do now please help me